# what's wrong with my code. it's sending html code as it is in gmail?

Tags: phpmailer

// send a custom email when the order status changes to "processing"
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'send_custom_email_order_processing', 10, 4 );
function send_custom_email_order_processing( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {

```
// only if the new order status is "processing"
if ( $to_status == 'processing' ) {
    $to_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <mailto:alexiglesiasvortex@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( $to_email, 'subject', '<h1>This is a test for my new pending email.</h1><p>Agree, this is a test</p>', $headers );
}
```

}

Comment: Can you format your code better?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not telling the client that the message body is in HTML, so it's handled as plain text.
You need to add a `content-type` header like this:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n";
```